# Get particular cell value for each checked row when header check box checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html-table

I have gridview having header checkbox and having checkbox on each row.. when I click on the header checkbox I need to check whether the child checkboxes are checked and if checked I need to get third Cell values of all checked rows ..

For this purpose I am doing like the below Javascript function:

```
 function toggleSelection(source) {
    $("#MainContent_gvCG input[id*='chkCert']").each(function (index) {
        if(source.checked) {
            if (this.checked) {

               ////Here i need to access the third cell values of all rows

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Sample table format (for better understanding):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>CFS Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>TCFSA</th>
    <th>CODEX</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkHeader"/></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRANSWORLD GLS INDIA</td>
    <td>Abc</td>
    <td>cg</td>
    <td>de</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkCert"></td>
  </tr>
  ................
  ...............
  ..............
  </table>
```

and this is my gridview:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gvPRCertInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"                     
           OnRowDataBound="gvPRCertInfo_RowDataBound"
            CssClass="data responsive">
             <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" SortExpression="">
                 <HeaderTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick="toggleSelection(this);"  OnCheckedChanged="chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged"/>
                     </HeaderTemplate>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCert" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkCert_CheckedChanged"  runat="server" />                                    
                         <input type="hidden" id="hdnCertId" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CertId") %>' />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CertificateID" HeaderText="Certificate ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         ....................
         .....................
         ..............
       </Columns>                            
   </asp:GridView>
```

Could any one please suggest any ideas on this how to access the third cell values for all checked rows .. any better solution other than this also welcome.

Modified code :

```
function toggleSelection(source) {
    $('#<%= gvPRCertInfo.ClientID %> input[id*="chkCert"]').each(function () {
            if (source.checked) {
                alert("source checked");
                if (this.checked) {
                    alert("child chk");
                    var allVlues = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(4)').html();
                    alert(allVlues);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not able  raise this alert **alert("child chk");** , could any one please help on this one..

Comment: `$(this).prev().prev();` will select the 3rd td. and then use `.text()` to get tht content inside it.

Comment: Suggest playing around in your console.  What is `console.log(this)`?  If you do something like `window.AA = this;` as the first line of your function, then you can access `AA` (which is `this` from the last function call) in your console, and see what condition you are assuming that is not the case.

Comment: use `$("#MainContent_gvCG input[id*='chkCert']:checked")` , this will only loop through checked checkboxes so you won't have to use `if (this.checked)`

Comment: is your Sample table format same as you have provided because i can see `class="chkCert"` and not `id` in it. Update your proper sample table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').text();`. Also notice the changes in `$("#MainContent_gvCG input.chkCert:checkbox").each(....`

```js
function toggleSelection(source) {
  $("#MainContent_gvCG input.chkCert:checkbox").each(function (index) {
      if(source.checked) {
          if (this.checked) {
             let thirdVal = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').text();
       console.log(thirdVal);
          }
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="MainContent_gvCG" >
  <tr>
    <th>CFS Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>TCFSA</th>
    <th>CODEX</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkHeader" onclick="toggleSelection(this);"/></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRANSWORLD GLS INDIA</td>
    <td>Abc</td>
    <td>cg</td>
    <td>de</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkCert"></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>mnl</td>
    <td>opq</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkCert" checked></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can treat this as a simple client-side only data collection, then select just what you want.  One example:

```
var $thirdCell = $(this).parent().children(':nth-child(3)');
console.log('Text: ', $thirdCell.text());
console.log('HTML: ', $thirdCell.html());
```

Depending on what you mean by 'value', you can get either text or HTML.

Comment: could you please look into that issue i have updated my code .. I am not able to raise that alert

Comment: I am not able to get into this  if loop  if (this.checked) {
                    alert("child chk");   ....   this check is for each row checkbox.. how can i get into this ....do u have any idea

Comment: Right.  As I asked in my comment above, what is the value of `this`?  What is your assurance that your function is even executing?